# Display function from functions.php in tag.php

Tags: functions, shortcode, tags

I've added several functions to the functions.php file. I call those functions using a shortcode `[shortCode]` while in posts, pages, and widgets. But the `[shortcode]` will not work outside of posts, pages, or widgets. I've tried it in article titles and in other files, but it doesn't work.

I'd like to add a `[shortcode]` to a function to my tag.php file, but I can't figure it out.

**EXAMPLE FUNCTION**

```
function dynamicContent(){
return 'some dynamic content';
}
add_shortcode('Dcontent', 'dynamicContent');
```

How can I get the `[Dcontent]` shortcode to work in the tag.php file?

Comment: But on the php way inside the theme is it better and faster to use the function that works for the shortcode - `echo dynamicContent()`, not a function for a function, like ? do_shortcode( 'Dcontent' )`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @bueltge for the answer! I was focusing on the shortcode and didn't even think to call the function in the 'normal' way.

```
echo dynamicContent()
```

worked.